# Getting an unusual/weird error in Pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have written simple `Pyspark` `filter` operation. It works, well. After the `filter`, I am doing `select`, where I see some unusual behavior in the code.

I tried many thing like. `persist` and `cache`. calling an `action` like `count()`. Nothing worked, I got this unusual error every time.

Let me share my code and `AWS Cloud Watch` logs.

Pyspark Code:

```py
print("inside header Snap")
headerDf.show()
aggSeqDf = headerDf.filter(col("header_identifier") != "DDDDSNAP")
aggSeqDf.show()
aggDf = aggSeqDf.select(SEQUENCE, "mn_id", "header_identifier").withColumnRenamed(SEQUENCE, SEQ).withColumnRenamed("mn_id", "mnId")
aggDf.show()
print("header snap ends here")
```

Cloud Watch Logs:

```
inside header Snap

+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------------+--------+
|           full_file|      mn_id|header_identifier|run_number|production_date|sequence|
+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------------+--------+
|Prod216_3427_ew_1...|          0|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
|Prod216_3427_ew_3...|          6|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
|Prod216_3427_ew_4...|         12|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
|Prod216_3427_ew_5...| 8589934592|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
|Prod216_3427_ew_6...| 8589934598|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
|Prod216_3427_ew_7...| 8589934604|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
| Prod216_3427_ni.dat|17179869184|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
| Prod216_3427_sc.dat|17179869190|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
|Prod216_3427_ew_2...|17179869196|         DDDDSNAP|      3427|       20230501| 0000000|
+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------------+--------+

+---------+-----+-----------------+----------+---------------+--------+
|full_file|mn_id|header_identifier|run_number|production_date|sequence|
+---------+-----+-----------------+----------+---------------+--------+
+---------+-----+-----------------+----------+---------------+--------+

+-------+-----------+-----------------+
|    seq|       mnId|header_identifier|
+-------+-----------+-----------------+
|0000000|          0|         00000001|
|0000000|          6|         00000003|
|0000000|         12|         00000004|
|0000000| 8589934592|         00000005|
|0000000| 8589934598|         00000006|
|0000000| 8589934604|         00000007|
|0000000|17179869184|         00000009|
|0000000|17179869190|         00000008|
|0000000|17179869196|         02550372|
+-------+-----------+-----------------+

header snap ends here
```

If you observe, I am doing a `select` from empty dataframe `aggDfSeq`  but I get few unexpected values in `aggDf`.

I am using `AWS Glue` to run the job. I attached the `whl` file of the Pyspark program in the Glue.

Even I tried changing the resources provided to the Glue, did not have a luck there also.

Would like to know from you, whyI am seeing this unusual behavior. Thank you

Physical and Logical plan added.

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Project [seq#829, mn_id#45L AS mnId#832L]
+- Project [sequence#192 AS seq#829, mn_id#45L]
   +- Project [sequence#192, mn_id#45L]
      +- Filter NOT (header_identifier#168 = DDDDSNAP)
         +- Project [full_file#5, mn_id#45L, header_identifier#168, run_number#169, production_date#170, sequence#192]
            +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, full_file#5, mn_id#45L, header_identifier#168, run_number#169, production_date#170, 0000000 AS sequence#192]
               +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, full_file#5, mn_id#45L, cast(substring(rest#40, 1, 8) as string) AS header_identifier#168, cast(substring(rest#40, 9, 4) as string) AS run_number#169, cast(substring(rest#40, 13, 8) as string) AS production_date#170]
                  +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, rest#40, full_file#5, mn_id#45L]
                     +- Join Inner, (mn_id#45L = min(mn_id)#67L)
                        :- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, rest#40, full_file#5, mon
otonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
                        :  +- Project [cast(substring(value#0, 1, 8) as string) AS company_number#38, cast(substring(value#0, 9, 1) as string) AS rec_type#39, cast(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) as string) AS rest#40, full_file#5]
                        :     +- Project [value#0, reverse(split(full_file#2, /, -1))[0] AS full_file#5]
                        :        +- Project [value#0, input_file_name() AS full_file#2]
                        :           +- Relation[value#0] text
                        +- Project [min(mn_id)#67L]
                           +- Aggregate [full_file#5], [full_file#5, min(mn_id#45L) AS min(mn_id)#67L]
                              +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, rest#40, full_file#5, monotonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
                                 +- Project [cast(substring(value#0, 1, 8) as string) AS company_number#38, cast(substring(value#0, 9, 1) as string) AS rec_type#39, cast(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) as stri
ng) AS rest#40, full_file#5]
                                    +- Project [value#0, reverse(split(full_file#2, /, -1))[0] AS full_file#5]
                                       +- Project [value#0, input_file_name() AS full_file#2]
                                          +- Relation[value#0] text

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
seq: string, mnId: bigint
Project [seq#829, mn_id#45L AS mnId#832L]
+- Project [sequence#192 AS seq#829, mn_id#45L]
   +- Project [sequence#192, mn_id#45L]
      +- Filter NOT (header_identifier#168 = DDDDSNAP)
         +- Project [full_file#5, mn_id#45L, header_identifier#168, run_number#169, production_date#170, sequence#192]
            +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, full_file#5, mn_id#45L, header_identifier#168, run_number#169, production_date#170, 0000000 AS sequence#192]
               +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, full_file#5, mn_id#45L, cast(substring(rest#40, 1, 8) as string) AS header_identifier#168, cast(substring(rest#40, 9, 4) as string) AS run_
number#169, cast(substring(rest#40, 13, 8) as string) AS production_date#170]
                  +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, rest#40, full_file#5, mn_id#45L]
                     +- Join Inner, (mn_id#45L = min(mn_id)#67L)
                        :- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, rest#40, full_file#5, monotonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
                        :  +- Project [cast(substring(value#0, 1, 8) as string) AS company_number#38, cast(substring(value#0, 9, 1) as string) AS rec_type#39, cast(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) as string) AS rest#40, full_file#5]
                        :     +- Project [value#0, reverse(split(full_file#2, /, -1))[0] AS full_file#5]
                        :        +- Project [value#0, input_file_name() AS full_file#2]
                        :           +- Relation[value#0] text
                        +- Project [min(mn_id)#67L]
                           +- Aggregate [full_file#5], [full_file#5, min(mn_id#45L) AS min(mn_id)#67L]
              
                +- Project [company_number#38, rec_type#39, rest#40, full_file#5, monotonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
                                 +- Project [cast(substring(value#0, 1, 8) as string) AS company_number#38, cast(substring(value#0, 9, 1) as string) AS rec_type#39, cast(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) as string) AS rest#40, full_file#5]
                                    +- Project [value#0, reverse(split(full_file#2, /, -1))[0] AS full_file#5]
                                       +- Project [value#0, input_file_name() AS full_file#2]
                                          +- Relation[value#0] text

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [0000000 AS seq#829, mn_id#45L AS mnId#832L]
+- Join Inner, (mn_id#45L = min(mn_id)#67L)
   :- Project [mn_id#45L]
   :  +- Filter (isnotnull(rest#40) AND NOT (substring(rest#40, 1, 8) = DDDDSNAP))
   :     +- Project [substring(value#0, 1, 1250) AS rest#40, monotonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
   :        +- Relation[value#0] text
   +- Filter
 isnotnull(min(mn_id)#67L)
      +- Aggregate [full_file#5], [min(mn_id#45L) AS min(mn_id)#67L]
         +- Project [reverse(split(full_file#2, /, -1))[0] AS full_file#5, monotonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
            +- Project [input_file_name() AS full_file#2]
               +- Relation[value#0] text

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [0000000 AS seq#829, mn_id#45L AS mnId#832L]
   +- BroadcastHashJoin [mn_id#45L], [min(mn_id)#67L], Inner, BuildRight, false
      :- Project [mn_id#45L]
      :  +- Project [substring(value#0, 1, 1250) AS rest#40, monotonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
      :     +- Filter (isnotnull(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) AS rest#40) AND NOT (substring(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) AS rest#40, 1, 8) = DDDDSNAP))
      :        +- FileScan text [value#0] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) AS rest#40), NOT (substring(substring(value#0, 1, 1250) AS..., Format: Text, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://ubo-mvp-oad/
landing_SNAP], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<value:string>
      +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [id=#3815]
         +- Filter isnotnull(min(mn_id)#67L)
            +- HashAggregate(keys=[full_file#5], functions=[min(mn_id#45L)], output=[min(mn_id)#67L])
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(full_file#5, 4), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#3811]
                  +- HashAggregate(keys=[full_file#5], functions=[partial_min(mn_id#45L)], output=[full_file#5, min#149L])
                     +- Project [reverse(split(full_file#2, /, -1))[0] AS full_file#5, monotonically_increasing_id() AS mn_id#45L]
                        +- Project [input_file_name() AS full_file#2]
                           +- FileScan text [] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: Text, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://ubo-mvp-oad/landing_SNAP], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use `aggDf.explain()` before show() to see how your dataframe is really constructed.

Comment: posted the physical and logical plan also.